# How can I have one explicit and one inferred type parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working with a UI-library that has an API for building tables similar to this:

```js
type Column<Record> = {
    keys: string | Array<string>;
    render: (prop: any, record: Record) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

The first argument to the render function will be provided by the library by doing basically `column.render(record[column.keys], record)`. If `column.keys` is an array, it instead interprets as a "path" down the record, about like this: `record[keys[0]][keys[1]]...[keys[keys.length - 1]]`. The example below is slightly altered so it uses the `Pick<...>` algorithm instead, just to have a simpler but still functional example.

```js
// Our record type
interface Entity {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

// helper type, does the following:
// GetOrPickProps<Entity, 'a'> -> Entity['a']
// GetOrPickProps<Entity, ['b', 'c']> -> Pick<Entity, 'a' | 'c'>
type GetOrPickProps<E, K extends (keyof E | Array<keyof E>)> = K extends keyof E
    ? E[K]
    : K extends Array<infer K2>
        ? Pick<E, K2 & keyof E>
        : never;

// My first attempt at a Column type
type Column<E, K extends (keyof E | Array<keyof E>)> = {
    keys: K;
    render: (prop: GetOrPickProps<E, K>) => string;
}

// ...but it doesn't work
const columns: Array<Column<Entity, /* What goes here??? */>> = [
    {
        keys: 'a',
        render: a => a,
    },
    {
        keys: ['a', 'c'],
        render: ({ a, c }) => c ? a : 'something else',
    }
]
```

If I explicitly put `'a' | ['a', 'c']` as the second parameter to `Column`, the type of both render functions will be `(prop: Entity['a'] | Pick<Entity, 'a' | 'c'>) => string`.

If I make the second parameter to `Column` optional (maybe like `K extends ... = unknown`) typescript won't actually infer the type anymore, instead explicitly using `unknown` as the type of `prop`.

How can I have a type that infers part of it's props in order to constrain other props, but also accepts an explicit type parameter?

TS-playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGSOTgC5kBnMKUAcwG5DiAjckAVwFtnpHjkE5ZgHthAGwhwQjAL7582AA4oA4hDAB5KAAVgCANbaowxRQA8qADTIA0sggAPSCAAmFZAAp9ELMJhpkAB9kAEEoKDgsM29ff1QAPgBKeOQAXlt7JwhXdxi-NCYiAH40AG0bAF1C5HI7R2c3UPDIs1AYaFsAJnjq-hLdAwtrG07kADJkPLie-n42CAA3XnklFABhcS4QIYz67MavH3zUIKaIqKm0JJT0gn4Yilq%20Yih96HIPRXI1TR09Q2Mph2NiSaRSVBoIAY%20Dk%20AQwhAVAEm04iPIYXOZg2Yi2Fgw2GsAHoAFTIADqAAs4GBkLRhBB3BToBAiqzkMTCfEbshStU7rMiA9yAByODCyy9F5vKDkOBgkgS-gyRXEfkCoU80Xi5DChDCioqgWvVzvTy4BUCZAyRLyhDIEpykUUYScdQUuj2MQUCDi6pyKr4QmE5AuekUEDCmkAd2EUH0pDhCKR8JxqMeZxa2Nx6DAmCw1i1p1KWoLeoqXLSPL5ksFPnTJZryGNLlNctSKTghqtXbVsw1xbFpf1Xf4zdNHnNnct1tt9pINR1ztdYHdUM93t9SvwVSAA).

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if it works for you:

```js
interface Entity {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

type Column<Key, Arg> = {
    keys: Key,
    render: (arg: Arg) => string
}

type Keys = 'a' | ['a', 'c'];


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
    U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credits https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
    ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
    : [T, ...A];


type ReducerElem = string;

type Reducer<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<ReducerElem>,
    Result extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends ReducerElem
    ? Result & Record<H, H>
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<ReducerElem>
    ? H extends ReducerElem
    ? Reducer<Tail, Result & Record<H, H>>
    : never
    : never
    : never;

type MapPredicate<T> =
    T extends string
    ? Column<T, T>
    : T extends Array<string>
    ? Column<T, Reducer<T>>
    : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

type Result = Mapped<UnionToArray<'a' | ['a', 'c']>>;


const columns: Result = [
    {
        keys: 'a',
        render: a => a,
    },
    {
        keys: ['a', 'c'],
        render: ({ a, c }) => c ? a : 'something else',
    }
]
```

If you agree with this solution I will provide more explanation.

Apart from that, [here](https://catchts.com/tuples) and [here](https://catchts.com/union-array) , in my blog, you can find some exmplanation

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGSOTgC5kBnMKUAcwG5DiAjckAVwFtnpHjkE5ZgHthAGwhwQjAL7582AA4oAwuK4gAPAGkIWADTIAglFoA%20ZAF48TIgGs9FcroO3kUCCAAm0cgAo4U3ITWgBKKwsqGhBafDkFLGVkFworZAByOHTkAB9kAG1M9MN0hHSAXUZ5AHpqgQ8vTFTaYQhUsGFkAAswMEUnWqpEO2EAN2gYMWEAdwA6BGFOarhqgFYABgBmAHZVgCYADgA2BKSAVRBgYRAAFWEASXBoCggEMCutM4trPzPkCAAHpBvKkpDgAPzIPx2chncKWCyjYTALzINgQcZQcKA4FeVJ%20Nww5CgGDQZD3fDwxHIrxuSEU-jozFVWr1CCNMDNVrtTo9PoDaq0TBddjMeaLaqcYAIKDCCjCGBgao3RIQADKMuAiiVwAoFHYbWqAEZNnsAJwHADEuv1r0WnE8YAAtAAWI4HI1Gl1m9ZG04oC4fO4AeVGYjxmi%20aUD1zuj0gUBebw%20mjcfxxnjxJBAEKhMFhVOQSJRaOQIAx0HwZhZdRl7KayBabWQHW6vX6pFqQrAIrFCyWUplcoVSpVyg1NG11RtBooxtNFuteoN-Yd4Fd7s93t9-uQAAVhIoY59vshjyGwxGoxmQVCyMSQKSoMZC8XUZCjKXy8yarWGg2%20Q7QYwGGMYJimOZ%202qdgXkTY09lWbZNhdap3neKQnSQKBLgWUY4CdLwoDgFopSgXd7goY9NBuU98hucp-iBTNUnyc8HieRNXnea5qLMBjIXgMQXlLagDSqJQA0uWNhBMIisGowxPxvLN2BAOwQBmEB8gY6xtNPCiqJoxjcXaKADTpM8pNuGSoDkzRUABBAxHYHwFP3Q9DLMMxDHyA8jys3jDFmYKjHKMw3HIOigpCyp5F3AAldl2Cw1AJE4NIojocTVWQRKvGS6BU34WTjOY3LJC8a4xCwWS4HkvKCqgVKIE4by3ES-UxDAUrb0ShYoC8TRMpiQwwVPXA5H4U8SuUljygsjr2C6iLjFsnqs3yEkyQACXm-hIW29bUgalK0oWtolu6gAycr%20sG7bDG28LGTLCsyJemamNvDw4EqkBqoKLbnwe5BgtmIHkBuOBgDEPbiEhKGYaO8rfqqmrbLqzQTugZrWosw7ZvK-LTpa87icKxGxEMRauuQG6%20uEAbNBBp7nuIJlKxe79OfZ16f13ABZOBFD3f8EDgSBeKsNwbmR4bYn25A1GczgtBuQwaJW2XCdq%20T5bZohIWVjQ3OxqBeINr83vkCTkCFxRlEGtxPpM1a7NU9TNLa-gae6nWMfkj2NOmEBaLhohprWwntIsmOPqjr6Noh3bY7B33DHt0X63FyWnvD0sXbKzbHx2irovBkvn0p-PIXtx3NHyMHq58tOLq6jPhazxoc4gZmKr4y3yES1H-vqtuwGrG2ct9tI6-ZSMrLuXXNCKXICiKEoyjCyf5AWEAqAEdRVaccrOu63S3AIfh%20AcLAT43tx%20A8bxfBICISH0NwZE--gr%20v%20xHCRQ3hkLeP9-7uEzK-PwuAP4CGQDIQsCBkCQjgKWdI8oHQ9joP8ISEBihf3wPNIAA)

This is js analogue of `Reducer` utility type

```js
const reducer = (arr: ReadonlyArray<Elem>, result: Record<string, any> = {}): Record<string, any> => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return result
    }

    const [head, ...tail] = arr;

    return reducer(tail, { ...result, [head]: 'string' })
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use helper function, but there is drawback. You still have to provide explicit type. Good news - TS will complain if explicit type is not allowed.

```js
interface Data {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

type Column<Key, Arg> = {
    keys: Key,
    render: <T extends Arg>(arg: T) => string
}


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
    U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credits https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
    ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
    : [T, ...A];


type ReducerElem = string;

type Predicate<T> = T extends keyof Data ? Record<T, Data[T]> : never

type Reducer<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<ReducerElem>,
    Result extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends ReducerElem
    ? Result & Predicate<H>
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<ReducerElem>
    ? H extends ReducerElem
    ? Reducer<Tail, Result & Predicate<H>>
    : never
    : never
    : never;

type MapPredicate<T> =
    T extends string
    ? Column<T, T>
    : T extends Array<keyof Data>
    ? Column<T, Reducer<T>>
    : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;


type Format<Keys extends ReadonlyArray<keyof Data>> =
    UnionToArray<Keys[number]> extends ReadonlyArray<string>
    ? Reducer<UnionToArray<Keys[number]>>
    : never


interface Union<Keys extends keyof Data> {
    keys: Keys,
    render: (a: Data[Keys]) => void
}

interface WithArray<Keys extends ReadonlyArray<keyof Data>> {
    keys: Keys,
    render: (a: Format<Keys>) => void
}


type Base<Keys> = Keys extends Array<keyof Data> ? WithArray<Keys> : Keys extends keyof Data ? Union<Keys> : any

const builder = <V extends Array<keyof Data>, U extends keyof Data>(columns: [...(Base<[...V]> | Base<U>)[]]) => columns

const result = builder([{
    keys: ['c'], render: (prop: Record<"c", boolean>) => prop
}, {
    keys: 'b', render: (prop) => prop
}])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBEEQag3sVQ1BALlQGcIZwBzAbgKICMywBXAWydgaNSTJMA9kIA2UBGAYBfYMAgBPAA5oAwmM5gAPAGkoCgDSoAgjBoA%20VAF48jQgGt95MnsN3UMKGAAmsMloAVVCgAD2gfchMzcwAKBDMyAIBKa0tKajAaYFk5AHpc-k9vEAhImiEoSIghVAALCAglZ3zKZHshADdYOFEhAHcAOiQhDlyEXIBWAAYAZgB2CYAmAA4ANnllNABVMBAhMAChAElIWHIoJAg97S3LGxit4LCvb0jJBVQAflQY%20zItlJWSwdIQgbyoVhQLowFKhcKvH7uP6ocBwWCoI7AQHA0HedzfTF8SHQhjAfKFKDFUqocqVVDVOoNJokfI0Eq1NhMIYjXIcEBIGBCchCOAQXIBTYAZQFICUYpA5HIbEquQAjDNFgBOZYAYgVSouIw4XggAFoACyrZaq1XmzVTVUbFSoHbXQ4AeQ6oleWlu1hdu32hxO0Bg50u1y07kecJebzAH2%20MTg-2xqBBYIhqDAUNgwHMpPJAspJTKFSqNXqjWauTZEA5XOGoz5AqFIrFEpU0uocty%20uV5DVGu1esVyqbxsgFqtNrtDqdaAACkIlK79r67gG3UJPd7yBunvDInEyKj0cY0xnwd9jFmcyS8gVi1TIlXmS1sEh2tCev1uaM2HOMM1UWCY5hmc1ciuK5JFNFAYF2YYOgQU1vBgBByj5GAFwxcg120AJNwAbQCABdQ841QIj8ODU4wwuK510I8jvkQURzizKhlVJRRnRooRTHQhRAiMW9YwiVA2DAewwH6MAiPImwFM3I48MDAjLHEhEuKgfEtyDASYCErQAFEQiQUQ2F8ETUGXVd1MCcxzCMIi7PwxyjAGLzjFI8x3DIEjPO80jSRwgAlSk2HgkzxA4f10loHjNlsop%20SwKBHP9IItMiRwFBFDAsBwb4IuGGBvBszBsBI3y71zbDwsi%20Coz4QSKIkiKEG8fZRAUQSEGEiLvCi2AYqgDhnPcCKlVECB2oRUqhHKrQEsyIx3k3XBZD4Tc2pyqjSL06a2Fm-yohgebIiIs8LoACUOvhvluy7UCGkaYDGjgjsqE65oAMhSkskHSrRbr8ols3qs69ueCTPC6nqPmusA0TuoKBhu1AAgQEBRAeohvmx3GXs67qwF6-rBqa0bYvBgnUGe-a3ui2LvuG5qidEIxjtm1AAcXVLgegUGnLO%2088wh8XsMl%20qkudABZBAlAFoGQcI6x3Gy2GEVWrJHtQdRLI4AijEIs6taPc6Bq0PKCqqhA6cIb5Dc0GzmdgRzHbq6E5F4tBFaUFQKvcGHLcprQpJkuTJr4Hm5v28PI9kvowGI-HCF2oyXoUvSc4h0PKOR1GGfTr4qK8gY46MAOVeKIWMrB0uyALiSi-RW6JG8dHMc50vvgDoOtCIive5ciuq9QGvBZBjuuvMXyztJxGtDjgs5BwgAxJaOCwXQnBJzvEfD224EK7AnI1vh%20PD1xyCI9guFgWqmcP8m%20qM63da9krqZgX11MODfJw99ODcBgL5L2xI8xyHAKGRAKB9LaFvi9E%20Z8Ha2D4HlZwqBb4GHcJ4HwfgfikDQURW%20pFLy4myDAui8C0AAHV2RAIUJEF%20CM37H30HbIqF98CYKcC4JweC%20AEN8DAMgJ5UBbxgDvCAe8WHmEoWCahvtkoACEEDnHkeQTcyCE4f2Eqg%202lhviMPrMwnRWY9Ha1ylw0%209sy7uVvpYMg7w5DDDAJQVATA2C4zEf6LQAA1F6nD8r2J4UYGMNjUBGJ4TEYYRtPEBQrjEDRWjh5eUCbVAAPqgNJGVbhJAUhQ1I-ANDG3IO4-YXjPAzTmjYHxfjYAxCInwogWCAoAHIkCdNIkYURRCYhKEFEoMgi1loACIkATKMMIMQEhU5pmGSubIRg2kOAEagTpTBOn9JeIM5ZSglkjOyBQ4AQA)

You can also make union of all possible values. Smth similar like I did [here](https://catchts.com/union-partial). But if your `Entity` interface contains more than 5 props, it will not work.

Or, you can use helper for each entity:

```js
interface Data {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

type Column<Key, Arg> = {
    keys: Key,
    render: <T extends Arg>(arg: T) => string
}


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
    U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credits https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
    ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
    : [T, ...A];


type ReducerElem = string;

type Predicate<T> = T extends keyof Data ? Record<T, Data[T]> : never

type Reducer<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<ReducerElem>,
    Result extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends ReducerElem
    ? Result & Predicate<H>
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<ReducerElem>
    ? H extends ReducerElem
    ? Reducer<Tail, Result & Predicate<H>>
    : never
    : never
    : never;

type MapPredicate<T> =
    T extends string
    ? Column<T, T>
    : T extends Array<keyof Data>
    ? Column<T, Reducer<T>>
    : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;


type Format<Keys extends ReadonlyArray<keyof Data>> =
    UnionToArray<Keys[number]> extends ReadonlyArray<string>
    ? Reducer<UnionToArray<Keys[number]>>
    : never

function maker<K extends Array<keyof Data>>(keys: K, cb: (a: Format<K>) => void): { keys: K, render: (a: Format<K>) => void }
function maker<K extends keyof Data>(keys: K, cb: (a: Data[K]) => void): { keys: K, render: (a: Data[K]) => void }
function maker(keys: keyof Data | Array<keyof Data>, cb: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    return {
        keys,
        render: cb
    }
}

const COLUMNS = [
    maker('a', (prop /** stirng */) => { }),
    maker(['a'], (prop /** Record<"a", string> */) => { }),
    maker('b', (prop /** Record<"a", string> */) => { })
] as const
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBEEQag3sVQ1BALlQGcIZwBzAbgKICMywBXAWydgaNSTJMA9kIA2UBGAYBfYMAgBPAA5oAwmM5gAPAGkoCgDSoAgjBoA%20VAF48jQgGt95MnsN3UMKGAAmsMloAVVCgAD2gfchMzcwAKBDMyAIBKa0tKajAaYFk5AHpc-k9vEAhImiEoSIghVAALCAglZ3zKZHshADdYOFEhAHcAOiQhDlyEXIBWAAYAZgB2CYAmAA4ANnllNABVMBAhMAChAElIWHIoJAg97S3LGxit4LCvb0jJBVQAflQY%20zItlJWSwdIQgbyoVhQLowFKhcKvH7uP6ocBwWCoI7AQHA0HedzfTF8SHQhjAfKFKDFUqocqVVDVOoNJokfI0Eq1NhMIYjXIcEBIGBCchCOAQXIBTYAZQFICUYpA5HIbEquQAjDNFgBOZYAYgVSouIw4XggAFoACyrZaq1XmzVTVUbFSoHbXQ4AeQ6oleWlu1hdu32hxO0Bg50u1y07kecJebzAH2%20MTg-2xqBBYIhqDAUNgwHMpPJAspJTKFSqNXqjWauTZEA5XOGoz5AqFIrFEpU0uocty%20uV5DVGu1esVyqbxsgFqtNrtDqdaAACkIlK79r67gG3UJPd7yBunvDInEyKj0cY0xnwd9jFmcyS8gVi1TIlXmS1sEh2tCev1uaM2HOMM1UWCY5hmc1ciuK5JFNFAYF2YYOgQU1vBgBByj5GAFwxcg120AJNwAbQCABdQ841QIj8ODU4wwuK510I8jvkQURzizKhlVJRRnRooRTHQhRAiMW9YwiVA2DAewwH6MAiPImwFM3I48MDAjLHEhEuKgfEtyDASYCErQAFEQiQUQ2F8ETUGXVd1MCcxzCMIi7PwxyjAGLzjFI8x3DIEjPO80jSRwgAlSk2HgkzxA4f10loHjNlsop%20SwKBHP9IItMiRwFBFDAsBwb4IuGGBvBszBsBI3y71zbDwsi%20Coz4QSKIkiKEG8fZRAUQSEGEiLvCi2AYqgDhnPcCKlVECB2oRUqhHKrQEsyIx3k3XBZD4Tc2pyqjSL06a2Fm-yohgebIiIs8LoACUOvhvluy7UCGkaYDGjgjsqE65oAMhSkskHSrRbr8ols3qs69ueCTPC6nqPmusA0TuoKBhu1AAgQEBRAeohvmx3GXs67qwF6-rBqa0bYvBgnUGe-a3ui2LvuG5qidEIxjtm1AAcXVLgegUGnLO%2088wh8XsMl%20qkudABZBAlAFoGQcI6x3Gy2GEVWrJHtQdRLI4AijEIs6taPc6Bq0PKCqqhA6cIb5Dc0GzmdgRzHbq6E5F4tBFaUFQKvcGHLcprQpJkuTJr4Hm5v28PI9kvowGI-HCF2oyXoUvSc4h0PKOR1GGfTr4qK8gY46MAOVeKIWMrB0uyALiSi-RW6JG8dHMc50vvgDoOtCIive5ciuq9QGvBZBjuuvMXyztJxGtDjgs5BwgAxJaOCwXQnBJzvEfD224EK7AnI1vh%20PD1xyCI9guFgWqmcP8m%20qM63da9krqZgX11MODfJw99ODcBgL5L2xI8zADgFJCM%20xUA70cH-HQL1j76DtkVJyvwnAuCMEgFgPxSCoC3jAHeEBdDmEvLiJIZBcCoDys4VAOgjCeB8H4IhZBSHkModQzMshYFgHgWARBCBkG6BeifM%20DscEKCYSw-ghCTzSKIjoUifDvC0LwAw3BzDWEvA4co%202qj1GpHTLiVAAi4GMREUg2AsimFSPtqgAAPlbYSTisH4KURXeINAmHvAUholI%20A%20CeAgGwBCtg%20B8EYQYdwYSDEwDIAQ9wsgcjDDAJQA27oAAyWx5YADlJT%20iIu4OxMAYgAHIEBVKMDEJQgolCoFyAAKlaRQK4CEaCoFabkNM9DpBJHiXwCpMQiI1KqaRepjSVwtPaa9Q0y0ABECBllGC-r0-pZjBnDPKWI%20xVSmB1J%20LM5pbSOmLRWWsjZVBaCWD6QMyxSRgDkQQJETJlB15AA)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this isn't really what I am looking for. I don't want to state the type of `keys` at all, it should be inferred instead.